# Django AttributeError when trying to add an object to a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have a webapp where I have a friends system. You guys here helped me out with that earlier, but now I have another problem.

Here is my models in `UserProfileInfo`

```py
friends = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True,related_name='user_connections')
```

And here is my AddFriendRedirect view

```py
class AddFriendRedirect(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj = get_object_or_404(UserProfileInfo,slug=username)
        url_ = obj.get_absolute_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user in obj.friends.all():
                obj.friends.remove(user)
                user.friends.remove(obj) # these are the fields causing the error
            else:
                obj.friends.add(user)
                user.friends.add(obj) # these are the fields causing the error
        return url_
```

And here is the error

> AttributeError at /mainapp/profile/don0024/add/
>   'User' object has no attribute 'friends'
>
> > Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in get
>     188.         url = self.get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests\mainapp\views.py" in
>   get_redirect_url
>     238.                 user.friends.remove(obj)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\don0024\interests\interests_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py"
>   in inner
>     257.         return func(self._wrapped, *args)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /mainapp/profile/don0024/add/
>   Exception Value: 'User' object has no attribute 'friends'

The `obj.friends.remove(user)` removes and adds the current user to the ManyToMany field on `obj`.
How am I able to do the opposite at the same time, so add `obj` to the current user's manytomanyfield?

So I am wondering if there is a way to solve this error that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/

By default To add friends to a user you need to use _set

`user.friends_set.add(obj)`

However you have overwritten the related name with "user_connections", so i believe you should do

`user.user_connections.add(obj)`

Comment: Thanks for that, but I am now getting this error 

`'User' object has no attribute 'friends_set'`
Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks for the extra help, but now with that new change, it's not getting reflected in the database. Only the original one is.
So like the new one doesnt produce any errors, it just doesn't commit it to the database

Comment: Have you synced the database since creating the relationship?

Comment: I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Unknown command.
If I remember correctly, they removed that when 2.0 arrived